# Internal links are not working on merged PDF files

Tags: java, itext

I am currently modifying the logic for generating a PDF report, using itext package (itext-2.1.7.jar). The report is generated first, then - table of contents (TOC) and then TOC is inserted into the report file, using PdfStamper and it's method - replacePage:

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader(finalFile.getAbsolutePath()),
            new FileOutputStream(reportFile));
stamper.replacePage(new PdfReader(tocFile.getAbsolutePath()), 1, 2);
```

However, I wanted TOC to also have internal links to point to the right chapter. Using replacePage() method, unfortunately, removes all links and annotations, so I tried another way. I've used a method I've found to merge the report file and the TOC file. It did the trick, meaning that the links were now preserved, but they don't seem to work, the user can click them, but nothing happens. I've placed internal links on other places in the report file, for testing purposes, and they seem to work, but they don't work when placed on the actual TOC. TOC is generated separately, here's how I've created the links (addLeadingDots is a local method, not pertinent to the problem):

```
Chunk anchor = new Chunk(idx + ". " + chapterName + getLeadingDots(chapterName, pageNumber) + " " + pageNumber, MainReport.FONT12);                 
String anchorLocation = idx+chapterName.toUpperCase().replaceAll("\\s","");
anchor.setLocalGoto(anchorLocation);
line = new Paragraph();                 
line.add(anchor);

line.setLeading(6);
table.addCell(line);
```

And this is how I've created anchor destinations on the chapters in the report file:

```
Chunk target = new Chunk(title.toUpperCase(), font);        
String anchorDestination = title.toUpperCase().replace(".", "").replaceAll("\\s","");           
target.setLocalDestination(anchorDestination);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(target);
p.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER); 
doc.add(p);
```

Finally, here's the method that supposed to merge report file and the TOC:

```
public static void mergePDFs(String originalFilePath, String fileToInsertPath, String outputFile, int location) {

    PdfReader originalFileReader = null;
    try {
        originalFileReader = new PdfReader(originalFilePath);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("ITextHelper.addPDFToPDF(): can't read original file: " + ex);
    }
    PdfReader fileToAddReader = null;
    try {
        fileToAddReader = new PdfReader(fileToInsertPath);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("ITextHelper.addPDFToPDF(): can't read fileToInsert: " + ex);
    }

    if (originalFileReader != null && fileToAddReader != null) {
        int numberOfOriginalPages = originalFileReader.getNumberOfPages();
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfCopy copy = null;
        try {
            copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
            document.open();

            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfOriginalPages; i++) {
                if (i == location) {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= fileToAddReader.getNumberOfPages(); j++) {
                        copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(fileToAddReader, j));
                    }
                }
                copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(originalFileReader, i));
            }
            document.close();
        } catch (DocumentException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
            m_logger.error("ITextHelper.addPDFToPDF(): can't read output location: " + ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            m_logger.error(Level.SEVERE, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

So, the main question is, what happens to the links, after both pdf documents are merged and how to make them work? I'm not too experienced with itext, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're doing software archeology by using iText 2.1.7. Version 5.5.9 was released in March and 7.0.0 was released this month. The official documentation on http://developers.itextpdf.com is based on those versions.

Comment: I concur with Amedee: your question is documented for iText 5. There is no valid reason why you'd use iText 2.1.7 given [technical and legal issues with that version](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/can-itext-217-or-earlier-be-used-commercially).

Comment: I've upgraded to itext 5.5.9.  The problem is still there.